# Formatting text in sublime using regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I want to format my file containing keywords which is alphabetically sorted, something like this:

```
...
national day
national
other
random
random2
...
```

and i want to put a space between keywords starting with different alphabets (meaning space between a's and b's and so on), which will look something like this:

```
...
national day
national

other

random
random2
...
```

I am doing this using regex and the regex which I tried is `\n(.{1,1})(?:.*?)\n(?!\1)`. This works fine for most cases except when there is only one occurrence of a keyword from one alphabet, in this case `other`. [Link to regex](https://regex101.com/r/Sd5qEh/1/).

As it can be seen `national` and `random2` are matching but `other` is not, although I believe there is every reason for it to.

The regex which works is `^(.{1,1})(?:.*?)\n(?!\1)` (first `\n` replaced by a `^`) but I need a reason for why is the first regex not matching with `other`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex consumes both newlines before and after that line. On the demo below, pay attention how the engine skips the `other` line:

[image]

You may fix the pattern with another lookaround, a `(?<=\n)` positive lookbehind: `(?<=\n)(.).*\n(?!\1)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sd5qEh/3).

However, you may use a more "linear" pattern with no lookarounds:

```
^(.).*(?:\n\1.*)*
```

Or if `\R` is supported:

```
^(.).*(?:\R\1.*)*
```

Replace with `$0\n`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sd5qEh/2).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `(.)` - Capturing group 1: any char other than a line break char
- `.*` - the rest of a line
- `(?:\n\1.*)*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `\n` - a newline
  - `\1` - same char as in Group 1
  - `.*` - the rest of the line.

Replace `\n` with `\R` to match any linebreak sequence.

Comment: Yes, i know its working when the regex starts with `^` , I want to know why isn't it working when the regex starts with `\n`

Comment: @gc7__ You must use `^` to match the start of a line. `\n` matches a line break.

Comment: But there is a line break after `national` and before `other`, and this will work when there are multiple keywords starting with an `o` and not when there is only one keyword starting with an `o`, that's my confusion

Comment: @gc7__  Your regex consumes both newlines before and after that line. You may fix the pattern with another lookaround: `(?<=\n)(.).*\n(?!\1)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Sd5qEh/3).

Comment: So are you saying that the `\n` at the end of `national` is consumed and therefore the `\n` at the start of `other` cannot read it, if this is the case then aren't matches supposed to be exclusive, thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @gc7__ Yes, I mean that your regex can't match `other` because the newline right before it has already been consumed with the preceding iteration.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look into `iterations consuming regex`, if there is any resource please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: I understand it now, its like `nationallergy` will match with `national` but not with 'allergy' in the regex `national|allergy` but will work with `national|(?<=al)lergy`. Thank you

Comment: @gc7__ I added as video showing how the engine skips `other`.

Comment: @gc7__ If I helped you, please consider upvoting/accepting the answer.